# Will it be justifiable to use Python concurrent for small efficiency?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm working on a Djnago project and I have a task , containing 3 smaller functions which are independent from each other, assume this:

```
def mainFunc():
  funA()
  funB()
  funC()
```

I used python `concurrent.futures` to edit function into this:

```
def mainFunc():
  with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
    executer.submit(funA)
    executer.submit(funB)
  funC()
```

I run both programs multiple times and I realized that the concurrent edition is running faster but only for about 20 milliseconds (as average), now my question is :

> Will it be justifiable to use Python concurrent for small efficiency? What could be downsides of using async programming vs sync programming in a case like that?

PS: as I mentioned this is a Django project and this function is a part of web service which might be called several times, maybe hundreds of times in a minute

Comment: The additional complexity of your app just to save 20ms is not worth it. Python runs only one thread at a time, plus there's additional cost for thread context switching, so there's very little justification to do this.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko thanks for your comment, I updated my question and added some details about project considerations

Comment: Are you saying that the thread pool `mainFunc` is 20ms faster on average than the single threaded version? If you're shaving off 20ms per request that might be worth while depending on your app. If you go this route it's common to have an app wide thread pool for network bound tasks as well (which is what I think you're probably using it for). That said asyncio (or some ASGI framework) might make your life easier if this is a common occurrence in your app.